# Hover state of element

Tags: javascript

I have div if i mouse over on div i need to call a handler and show hover card of user

my problem is when handler is running if i mouse out

but still am getting my hover card

this shouldn't happen

Is there any way in javascript i can know wheather element have hover state are not

```
showPopup: function() {
    moLikeDisLikeUsers.popup = 'show';
    var url = '/_service/getHoverCardDetails.ashx';
    var pars = Object.toQueryString({ 'prfid': moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid'), 'id': moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid'), 'ht': "1" });
    var target = 'output-div';

    if (Object.isUndefined(userkey.get(moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid'))) || (userkey.get(moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid'))) == '') {
        moLikeDisLikeUsers.ajax = new Ajax.Updater(target, url, { method: 'get', parameters: pars, onSuccess: function(transport) {
            var response = transport.responseText || "no response text";
            var data = transport.responseText.evalJSON(true);
            userkey.set(moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid'), data);
            if (moLikeDisLikeUsers.popup == 'show') {
                moLikeDisLikeUsers.drawPopup(data);
            }
        }
        });
    }
    else {
        moLikeDisLikeUsers.drawPopup(userkey.get(moLikeDisLikeUsers.options.get('profileid')));
    }
},
hidetip: function() {
    if (moLikeDisLikeUsers.tooltip) {
        AbortAjaxCall(moLikeDisLikeUsers.ajax);
        moLikeDisLikeUsers.popup = 'hidden';
        moLikeDisLikeUsers.tooltip.hide();
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0):

I imagine you could use `getComputedStyle` to figure out what the value of a property was on an element, and change it with an external stylesheet (defining different rules for `#foo` and `#foo:hover`), but you are probably better off writing logic that does the right thing (whatever that might be) when the `mouseover` and `mouseout` events fire.

Better yet, [don't show content on `:hover`](http://www.cennydd.co.uk/2010/end-hover-abuse-now/).